# Java IDE for iPhone

Tags: ide, iphone-app

I'm looking for an IDE for Java similar to Eclipse, but for iPhone. I'm wondering if it can be similar to Orion or another cloud-based compiler so that I can start a program on my computer and work on it on my iPhone without having to email the file to myself. I know that Orion has a web app that may work on iPhones, but I'm looking for an app optimized for iPhone/iPad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One that comes to mind is [CodeAnywhere.com](https://codeanywhere.com/) which supports syntax highlighting for Java. It's has an app for both [iPhone and iPad](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/codeanywhere/id436736239) as well as a great online interface.

> Codeanywhere is a text, code and markup editor, that has been
> redesigned and reengineered to be light, fast, and mobile-friendly.
> Connect to your FTP, SFTP Servers, Dropbox or Github account and
> easily manipulate your resources, folders or files just with the swipe
> of your finger.
>
> Share and collaborate on projects or just a single file -  from
> wherever you are, and of course quickly edit code with our keyboard
> that has been customised for developers on the go.
>
> Codeanywhere makes developers forget what device they are working on
> and let them concentrate on getting work done - be it from the iPad,
> iPhone, or the desktop.
>
> Codeanywhere, it lets you do just that.
>
> [image: Codeanywhere's UI]

Comment: Be warned - Codeanywhere in the App Store is only a 7 day trial version.

Answer (score 2):

I see you accepted the above answer, but I want to show you an alternative.
I've not used it yet, but heard a lot of good things about it and I'm sure you can find tests for it easily.

It's not free (9,99€) but it's for iPhone and iPad, and there is also a client for Mac.

[Coda for iOS](https://www.panic.com/coda-ios/)